# Disadvantages of the standalone auxiliary application instead of embedding it to main application

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded application running on Linux kernel. I need to add another auxiliary application that will communicate with the main application by opening a socket between two applications. There is another option to embed this auxiliary application to main application as a new thread, but this will cost so much time to rearrenge.

What is the advantages/disadvantages of using standalone auxiliary applications? What would be the possible misbehavior or problems that we would encounter? I am waiting for your wise hand-on and/or technical experience.

Thanks

Comment: *"What is the advantages/disadvantages of using standalone auxiliary applications?"* -- Define your use of *"standalone"* and *"auxiliary"*.  "Standalone" is usually opposite to application and OS, and synonymous with bare-metal.  In more conventional terminology, seems like you're trying to compare two processes (aka multiprocessing) versus multithreading.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python/3044626#3044626 and its comments, which are not really Python-specific.

Comment: See https://blogs.datalogics.com/2013/09/25/threads-vs-processes-for-program-parallelization/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to choose multithreading or multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928256/when-to-choose-multithreading-or-multiprocessing)

Comment: those sources would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disadvantages of communication over socket:

- Alower than shared memory.
- Additional coding effort.
- Third application might hijack socket.

Advantages of communication over socket:

- Easily extendable to usage of separate systems for the two processes.
- The two applications can be programmed in totally different languages and could use different bitness.
- One application can be changed without touching the other if the protocol stays the same.